# What is the copyright on scans of old books?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, public-domain

Let's consider a very old book (1600s) which is definitely on the public domain now. The book it's very rare and thus few people own physical copies of it.

One of these owners chooses to scan its copy of the book and makes the images available for free on the internet.

Are these images subjects to copyright?

Comment: Thanks everyone, while my question is a bit different, those answers do indeed address the same issue.